# SQL how to get a value from a cell in an access table

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, ms-access

*I'm using access table*

I'm using this oleDBManager that includes these public functions:

```
/// <summary>
/// Excecutes an SELECT query and returns the data.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="query">the query string</param>
/// <returns>returns an DataTable instance with the recived data from the selection query.</returns>
public DataTable ExcecuteRead(string query) {
    this.link.Open();
    // ---
    this.dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, this.link);
    // ---
    this.dataTable = new DataTable();
    this.dataAdapter.Fill(this.dataTable);
    // ---
    this.link.Close();
    // ---
    return this.dataTable;
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns an HTML table code, with all the rows and the values of the results.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="query">the query string</param>
/// <returns>returns an HTML code as a string</returns>
public string ExcecuteTableRead(string query)
{
    string output = "<table border=\"1\">";
    // ---
    this.dataTable = this.ExcecuteRead(query);
    // ---
    foreach (DataRow row in this.dataTable.Rows)
    {
        output += "<tr>";
        // ---
        foreach (object obj in row.ItemArray)
        {
            output += "<td>" + obj.ToString() + "</td>";
        }
        // ---
        output += "</tr>";
    }
    // ---
    output += "</table>";
    // ---
    return output;
}
/// <summary>
/// Returns an HTML table code, with all the rows and the values of the results.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="query">the query string</param>
/// <param name="max">the maximum number of rows to show</param>
/// <returns>returns an HTML code as a string</returns>
public string ExcecuteTableRead(string query, int max)
{
    int i = 0;
    string output = "<table border=\"1\">";
    // ---
    this.dataTable = this.ExcecuteRead(query);
    // ---
    foreach (DataRow row in this.dataTable.Rows)
    {
        if (i < max)
        {
            output += "<tr>";
            // ---
            foreach (object obj in row.ItemArray)
            {
                output += "<td>" + obj.ToString() + "</td>";
            }
            // ---
            output += "</tr>";
        }
        i++;
    }
    // ---
    output += "</table>";
    // ---
    return output;
}
```

In my "users" table, I have a "userid", "username", "password" and "logins" for each user.
My question is, when the user logins (I have the username and the password), how can I get the value of his 'logins' column?
Would be even better if I could set it into an int (if it matters, I've set the "logins" column in access to 'number' from 'text'.

Edit: what I'm trying to do is to update the number of times the user has logged in. If there's a better way, please tell me.

Comment: so basically i figured that the SQL Syntax should be
`"SELECT logins FROM users WHERE username='" + username + "'"`
but the problem is that when i'm using the ExcecuteRead() function it returns a DataTable type instead of an int or a string.
any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**answer:**

So, although no one answered me, i've managed to learn it myself:

here is the whole part of the code (username is the name of the user and also a string of it with the same name, logins is the column, users is the table)

```
string logins = db.ExcecuteTableRead("SELECT logins FROM users WHERE username='" + username + "'");
logins = logins.Substring(21, 20);
logins = Regex.Match(logins, @"\d+").Value;
int loginsInt = Int32.Parse(logins) + 1;
int a = db.ExecuteQuery("UPDATE users SET logins='" + loginsInt.ToString() + "' WHERE username='" + username + "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ExecuteScalar() function which returns object 
**OR** 
you can use ExecuteRead() and
store it in a string like this

```
string logins= dt.rows[0].itemarray[0].tostring()
```